# Nslookup: command not found error on RHEL/CentOS 7

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

During linux installation I selected "minimal" option:

[image]

When I went to run the nslookup command to look up an IP address I got the error message `nslookup: command not found` as shown in the example below.

```
$ nslookup www.google.com
bash: nslookup: command not found
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the `bind-utils` package, which includes the `nslookup` binary?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The minimal install likely did not come with the `bind-utils` package, which I believe contains `nslookup`.

You can install `bind-utils` with:

```
sudo yum install bind-utils
```

In general, you can search for what package provides a command using the `yum provides` command:

```
sudo yum provides '*bin/nslookup'
```

Comment: Or if you don't know where the command should live, `*/nslookup`.

Comment: I get `package bind-utils not found`

Comment: @Black If you are using `ubuntu`, use `apt-get install dnsutils -y` instead.

Comment: Also for Arch `dnsutils`

Comment: `yum install bind-utils -y`
worked for me on amazon linux docker image

Answer (score 31):

For those using **DEBIAN**, the package to use is **dnsutils** and the installation process should be, initiated with:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils -y
```

According to other users it is the same for **Ubuntu**